# Local data storage for .NET application

Tags: .net, windows, storage, local

I need a local storage for .NET/WPF application mainly for images and some other stuff. I'm not looking for a database solution here.
The requirements for the storage are:

1. Must be accessible only through this .NET application
2. It's ok that some administrator can access the storage (for cleaning, copying the data etc.) but I'd like to avoid that the user or any other application accidentially deletes the files here
3. Through .NET application the user can at runtime create, modify and delete folders and data
4. The storage is for a specific user who is using the application
5. When the .NET application is updated (either Windows Installer or ClickOnce) this storage should not be touched and all existing data must stay there to be used in the updated application

A typical scenario: The end user wants to save an image through the application. The app creates a folder and the image is saved there. Later on, that image can be read from there and shown to user on UI.

I read about [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but I'm not sure if this is what I should be looking for.

I also see many other applications use Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming folder to store application data. Should that be used?

Comment: Isolated storage is one option, a virtual file system such as our SolFS ( https://www.eldos.com/solfs/ ) is another option that seem to fit your requirements perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

IsolatedStorage is nice in that your user won't stumble upon it, but neither will an Admin unless they search for it.

The problem with IsolatedStorage for you, is how it's isolated, by which I mean the criteria used to select the storage.  When your assembly/exe changes major version, you're going to get a new store and the old data will be unreachable except through the old assembly.

I find Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) to be a good place to store data - it corresponds physically to

- WinXP: "c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data"
- WinV/7/8: "c:\ProgramData"